# ASP .NET MVC3: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, exception

I have a web-application developed in Asp. net MVC3 and worked fine in my localhost environment, but when I hosted the application online, it is creating problems at many points.

Like for instance, I have this particular page named **Fee Submission** that when I try to visit, shows me the following exception:

[image]

here is the image of rest of the exception

[image]

Following is my controller method :

```
// GET: /FeeSubmission
     public ActionResult FeeSubmission()
     {

         return View(niti.getStudentAndFeeDetails());
     }
```

##

and here is the getStudentAndFeeDetails() method definition :

```
##   public List<StudentFeeMapping> getStudentAndFeeDetails()
        {
            log.Info("FeeNiti :: getStudentAndFeeDetails : START");
            var newlist = from n in _dataBase.studentfeemappings
                          select new StudentFeeMapping
                          {
                              AdmissionNumber = n.AdmissionNumber,
                              FatherName = n.studentrecord.guardianrecords.FirstOrDefault().FirstName,
                              Batch = n.studentrecord.classrecord.ClassName + "-" + n.studentrecord.classrecord.Section,
                              FeeName = n.feerecord.FeeName,
                              FeeAmount = n.feerecord.FeeAmount,
                              StudentName = n.studentrecord.FirstName,
                              StudentFeeMappingID = n.StudentFeeMappingID,
                              DiscountAmountinCurrency = (from feeCollectiondateData in _dataBase.feerecords
                                                          where (feeCollectiondateData.CategoryID == n.studentrecord.CategoryID && feeCollectiondateData.discounttype == "Currency")
                                                          select feeCollectiondateData.FeeAmount).FirstOrDefault(),
                              DiscountAmountinPercentage = (from feeCollectiondateData in _dataBase.feerecords
                                                            where (feeCollectiondateData.CategoryID == n.studentrecord.CategoryID && feeCollectiondateData.discounttype == "Percentge")
                                                            select feeCollectiondateData.FeeAmount).FirstOrDefault(),
                              FeeID = n.FeeID,
                              date = n.studentrecord.classrecord.feecollectionrecords.FirstOrDefault().StartDate
                          };
            log.Info("FeeNiti :: getStudentAndFeeDetails : END");
            return newlist.ToList();
        } ##
```

Point to be noted here is that I have similar controller methods that are working fine. I am facing the issue just with this method operation.

Comment: If possible provide complete stack trace. That error seems to be an sql exception error. Byw, the StudentFeeMapping contains the date as a memeber?

Comment: Yes, StudentFeeMapping contains Date as a member. here StudentFeeMapping is a model Class.

Comment: Do you use the same database (MySql) & the same provider on your local and hosted environments? It looks like MySql provider cannot convert some linq expression to SQL query. But if you use the same code, db and provider it should fail on both machines.

Comment: Yes I am Using Same Database on both the machines. i am trying a lot to find the solution on internet but till now got no answer.